# how to re arrange woocommerce admin order detail page? like shows per order item wise shows shipping address and billing address?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hello can you please anyone help me to figure out this requirement

I need to show means re arrange woocommerce order admin detail page

like [this url](http://prntscr.com/efv2h6)

We need to remove first top div and merge it with order item wise
is it possible and if yes then please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please help me?

Comment: I have no experience in woocommerce..you will have to provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and people can help with your problems. Welcome to SO.

Comment: please share your code, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask